# How to pass a variable down through a set of chained methods?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to chain several methods to clean up my code. Here is what I've done:

```
const playerItemDropUpdates = this.players.list
   .map(player => player.inventory.itemDropId)
   .filter((itemDropId): itemDropId is ItemId => itemDropId != null)
   .map(itemDropId => this.createItemDrop(itemDropId, player, 1));
```

Unfortunately, in the second `map` method (4th line), it says `cannot find name 'player'.`

How can I fix this and make `player` accessible in the second `map`?

Comment: By the point the second `map` runs the player is already lost. It actually operates on a list of `itemDropId` with no reference to which player originated them.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to map to an array of item drops *or* undefined, then filter out all the undefined's, but you would still have to annotate or cast:

```
const playerItemDropUpdates: ItemDropType[] = this.players.list
    .map((player, index) => 
        player.inventory.itemDropId !== null
            ? this.createItemDrop(player.inventory.itemDropId, player, 1)
            : undefined
    ).filter(Boolean);
```